# Scroll to LHS is not taking place..?

Tags: scroll, robotium

I want to scroll my screen to LHS and RHS. So, iam using the following statement to scroll the screen to RHS and its working fine

```
solo.scrollToSide(Solo.RIGHT);
```

but when iam using the following statement to scroll the screen to LHS, the screen is not scrolling to left

```
solo.scrollToSide(Solo.LEFT);
```

even i tried solo.scrollToSide(21); 
but no use....?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use this method:

```
void drag(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int stepCount) 
Simulate touching the specified location and dragging it to a new location.
```

This is the official documentation about method:

```
drag
 public void drag(float fromX,
        float toX,
        float fromY,
        float toY,
        int stepCount) 
Simulate touching the specified location and dragging it to a new location.
 Parameters:fromX - X coordinate of the initial touch, in screen coordinatestoX - X coordinate of the drag destination, in screen coordinatesfromY - Y coordinate of the initial touch, in screen coordinatestoY - Y coordinate of the drag destination, in screen coordinatesstepCount - How many move steps to include in the drag
```

Comment: thanks mate........ I used the same above method on that day itself after posting this question. Its working fine... thanks